# Does facebook/google app id need to keep secret if possible?

Tags: google, facebook

For example, suppose I have an app which includes a link to use the facebook feed dialog, eg:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxxx&link=
```

Which means the Facebook id is revealed to outside. My question is, is revealing facebook/google app ID a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

Not a risk. The app ID is intended to be public; this is how you're supposed to use it.

The app secret is -- as the name implies -- the part which has to be kept private.